# How to remove an NSView's subview

Tags: nsview, subview, subviews

I have a problem with an NSView's subview. I'm trying to use an NSArray to retrieve [myView subviews] (in which I have only one view) and I want to remove this subview but I don't know how to do it. I have tried

```
   NSArray *subviews = [self.mainView subviews];
   [self.mainView replaceSubview:subviews[0] with:[self.mainViewController view]];
```

but XCode crashes and I get this log into the console :

```
   -[NSEvent subviews]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102202aa0
```

I don't know what the problem is....

So if some of you could help me, that would be very kind...

Answer (score 1):

Well, shame on me !

I was actually looking for a problem at the wrong place...

What I ended up doing is this : I have two subviews in my mainView, the one at index 0 is a background NSimageView (which I want to keep) and the second one (at index 1) is the one I want to replace.

So here's the solution :

```
NSArray *subviews = [self.mainView subviews];
NSView *secondSubView = [subviews objectAtIndex:1];
[self.mainView replaceSubview:secondSubView with:[self.myViewController view]];
```

Enjoy !